# Removing similar text from keys and values and simplify output

Tags: javascript, parsing, string-parsing

Hello I need to make parser to process data. I have input data like this.

```
http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/           -> Drupal, Apache, PHP 5, RedHat
http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/a         -> Drupal, Apache, PHP 5, RedHat
http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/a/1      -> Drupal, Apache, PHP 5, RedHat
http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/a/2      -> Drupal, Apache, PHP 5, RedHat
http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/a/3/4   -> Drupal, Apache, PHP 5, RedHat
http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/b         -> Drupal, Apache, PHP 5, RedHat
http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/c         -> Drupal, Apache, PHP 5, RedHat, jQuery
http://epfl.ch/site/jml                 -> Joomla, Apache, PHP 4, jQuery
http://epfl.ch/site/jml/pdfs         -> PDF generator
http://epfl.ch/site                       -> Apache, PHP 5
```

Need to output like this.

```
http://epfl.ch/site/                     -> Apache, PHP 5
http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/          -> Drupal, RedHat
http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/c        -> jQuery
http://epfl.ch/site/jml                -> Joomla, PHP 4, jQuery
http://epfl.ch/site/jml/pdfs        -> PDF generator
```

How to achieve this using javascript?

Comment: Is that input data is json...? Please specify cleanly your input and output

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've got the data as a js object, so I made my example based on that.

```
var data = {
  'http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/' : 'Drupal, Apache, PHP 5, RedHat',
  'http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/a/1' : 'Drupal, Apache, PHP 5, RedHat',
  'http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/a/2' : 'Drupal, Apache, PHP 5, RedHat',
  'http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/a/3/4' : 'Drupal, Apache, PHP 5, RedHat',
  'http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/b' : 'Drupal, Apache, PHP 5, RedHat',
  'http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/c' : 'Drupal, Apache, PHP 5, RedHat, jQuery',
  'http://epfl.ch/site/jml' : 'Joomla, Apache, PHP 4, jQuery',
  'http://epfl.ch/site/jml/pdfs' : 'PDF generator',
  'http://epfl.ch/site/' : 'Apache, PHP 5'
}

var correctFormat = [
  {'http://epfl.ch/site/' : 'Apache, PHP 5'},
  {'http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/' : 'Drupal, RedHat'},
  {'http://epfl.ch/site/drupal/c' : 'jQuery'},
  {'http://epfl.ch/site/jml' : 'Joomla, PHP 4, jQuery'},
  {'http://epfl.ch/site/jml/pdfs' : 'PDF generator'}
];
```

My best guess is that you would have to use regular expressions somehow in order to filter out the similar keys and values, but I've written an example function that uses `correctFormat` and filters out everything from `data` that is not in the correct format.

```
function simplifyOutput(input, correctFormatMap) {
  var result = [];

  for ( var key in input ) {    
    correctFormatMap.forEach(function(format) {
      var correctKey = Object.keys(format)[0];

      if (key.split(correctKey).length === 2 && key.split(correctKey)[1] === "") {
        var formattedObj = {};
        formattedObj[correctKey] = format[correctKey];
        result.push(formattedObj);
      }
    });

  }
  return result;
}
```

This is just a helper.

```
function sortByKey(inputData) {
  return inputData.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aKey = Object.keys(a);
    var bKey = Object.keys(b);
    return aKey > bKey;
  });
}
```

And here is how it would work, but this right now heavily relies on the hardcoded format data, basically returning it inside the function and I am not sure this is what you need...

```
console.log(sortByKey(simplifyOutput(data, correctFormat)));
```